# How to get maximum wait time from array of cars with fuel needed

Tags: php, algorithm

I have an array of cars $cars=array(2,8,4,3,2), where the values in the array show the fuel needed for the car. And there are three fuel stations say $x, $y, and $z. Each of the fuel station has limited capacity of fuel. Say $x=7, $y=11, $z=3. So when each car from the array move to the fuel station, it needs to check if there is enough fuel to fill if there is not then the car must wait untill one of the other is done filling and then only the next car can move to the fuel station. the time it takes to fill the tank is 1 second per gallon. So how to get maximum filling time for above mention array. so far i have done this

```
$cars=array(2,8,4,3,2);
$x=7; $y=11; $z=3;

echo maxwaittime($cars, $x, $y, $z);

function maxwaittime($cars, $x, $y, $z){
    $car1=0;
    $car2=0;
    $car3=0;

    $maximumtime=0;
    $i=0;
    while($i < count($cars)){
        if($car1 !=0 && $car2 !=0 && $car3 !=0){
            if($car1 < $car2){
                $mintime=$car1;
            }else{
                $mintime=$car2;
            }

            if($mintime > $car3){
                $mintime=$car3;
            }

            $car1=$car1-$mintime;
            $car2=$car2-$mintime;
            $car3=$car3-$mintime;

            $x=$x-$mintime;
            $y=$y-$mintime;
            $z=$z-$mintime;

            if($mintime > $maximumtime){
                $maximumtime=$mintime;
            }
        }

        if($car1==0){
            if($cars[$i] <= $x){
                $car1=$cars[$i++];
                continue;
            }else{
                return -1;
            }
        }else if($car2==0){
           if($cars[$i] <=$y){
                $car2=$cars[$i++];
                continue;
           }else{
                return -1
           }
        }else if($car3==0){
           if($cars[$i] <=$z){
                $car3=$cars[$i++];
                continue;
           }else{
                return -1
           }
        }
    }
    return $maximumtime;
}
```

The problem here is at the iteration of third car which needs 4 gallon of fuel and the fuel station z only has 3 gallons available the car should wait for 2 seconds and get fuel from station x after it gets free. but my code return -1. It should only return -1 if none of the station has desired fuel to fill.

In fact in above case it should return 8 as it is maximum wait time respectively 0, 0, 2, 2 and 8 seconds.

Answer (score -1):

```
            $car1=0;
            $car2=0;
            $car3=0;

            $maximumtime=0;
            $i=0;
            while($i < count($cars)){ 
     /*$car1 = 0 $car2=0 $car3 = 0 => false*/           if($car1 !=0 && $car2 !=0 && $car3 !=0){
                    if($car1 < $car2){
                        $mintime=$car1;
                    }else{
                        $mintime=$car2;
                    }

                    if($mintime > $car3){
                        $mintime=$car3;
                    }

                    $car1=$car1-$mintime;
                    $car2=$car2-$mintime;
                    $car3=$car3-$mintime;

                    $x=$x-$mintime;
                    $y=$y-$mintime;
                    $z=$z-$mintime;

                    if($mintime > $maximumtime){
                        $maximumtime=$mintime;
                    }
                }
                if($car1==0){
            if($cars[$i] <= $x){
                $car1=$cars[$i++];
                continue;
            }else{
                return -1;
            }
        }else if($car2==0){
           if($cars[$i] <=$y){
                $car2=$cars[$i++];
                continue;
           }else{
                return -1;
           }
/*/*$car3=0 => true*/*/
        }else if($car3==0){
/*$i=2 => $cars[2]= 4 $z = 3 => FALSE => return  -1*/
           if($cars[$i] <=$z){
                $car3=$cars[$i++];
                continue;
           }else{
                return -1;
           }
        }
    }
    return $maximumtime;
}
```

Comment: Its the same solution provided above except the mintime is in a function